# highlight expressions on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, plugins, expression, highlight

I want to know if there is a way to highlight the full content in an expression like if, while, etc.

I have to work in a code that is bad indented where expressions can cover over 1000 lines and I can't format it.

for exemple :

```
if ($somethingTrue) {
    while ($somethingHappen) {
    // 500 lines...
    }  }
  if ($someCondition) {
}
```

look, it's very hard to see the end of the first if and what it cover...

Does someone know if there is a native feature or plugin on netbeans that do this job ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any plugin/external jar file for achieving the same. Whichever expression you want to check the body of, just click on the opening brace after that expression and NetBeans will automatically show you the closing brace for that expression.

Basically, Netbeans shows the ending brace for a corresponding starting brace entry---for each of if-statements,loop-statements,method declarations,etc.

[image]

In the shown figure, see my if-statement starting with yellow brace(cursor blinking there), and the corresponding ending brace for the if-statement.

***EDIT :-***

You also can also have a brand new-code fold,just by typing **`fcom`**, and hitting **`(Tab)`** button on KeyBoard. And, then put whatever block you want inside it and done. Expand whenever you wish and collapse whenever you want.

[image]

Check the position of my mouse-pointer which shows the current block of if-statement. You can expand and collapse as per your wish. And, also you can have several of them for each of your expression-tree.

Comment: @Bang-Then, I don't have the idea how to achieve the same. I think experimenting somewhat more may lead you to the result.